# Heroku drops connection with db after little inactivity

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, heroku, persistence

I use *Spring + Hibernate + MySQL + Tomcat + Heroku(free account)*. When I start to use web-site everything works, but if I do not use pages with db-connection for a while db drops connection. At the same time in IntelliJ IDEA app keeps constant connection with the same db. What's the matter?

My persistence.xml (commented lines are tried out options):

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
         version="2.0">
<persistence-unit name="FlatsJPA" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <!--<property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://eu-cdbr-west-01.cleardb.com:3306/heroku_a2736c1ec063973?reconnect=true"/>-->
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://eu-cdbr-west-01.cleardb.com:3306/heroku_a2736c1ec063973?autoReconnect=true"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="b73b29b287469f" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="password" />
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>

        <!--<property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size" value="10"/>-->
        <!--<property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size" value="280"/>-->
        <!--<property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout" value="100"/>-->
        <!--<property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements" value="0"/>-->
        <!--<property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period" value="300"/>-->



        <!--<property name="hibernate.c3p0.autoCommitOnClose" value="false"/>-->
        <!--<property name="hibernate.c3p0.preferredTestQuery" value="SELECT 1"/>-->
        <!--<property name="hibernate.c3p0.unreturnedConnectionTimeout"-->
                  <!--value="60"/>-->

        <!--<property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size" value="5"/>-->
        <!--<property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size" value="20"/>-->
        <!--<property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout" value="1800"/>-->
        <!--<property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements" value="50"/>-->
        <!--<property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period" value="1800"/>-->
        <!--<property name="c3p0.idleConnectionTestPeriod" value="1810"/>-->


    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```